# Python - file management and processing multiple zip files

Tags: python, file

I have some zip files in a folder. I have a script to process them. The data that is to be written to a database is in a different file and its structure is as follows:

```
some_text;database;file_name
some_text2;database2;file_name2
....
```

What is the best way to process this file? Also, an error message should be reported if there is no matching zip file name in that file.

My current code:

```
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip'))
if filelist:
    for file in filelist:
        print "Working on file ", file
        #get only file name without .zip for compare
        aa = file.split(sl)
        bb = aa[len(aa) -1]
        cc = bb.split(".")
        ime_sole = cc[0]

        fle = codecs.open(rootdir + sl + 'portal_schools.txt',
                          'r',encoding="cp1250")
        line = fle.readline()

        # Read lines 
        for line in iter(fle):
            #print line,
            a,b,c = line.split(";")
            if c == ime_sole:
                print c
                database = str(b)
                #distdir = str(c)
             else:
                 print "some text"
                 return


        fle.close()
```

But this fails because it is being read line by line. If in the first line there is no match, the code stops. I need it to continue trough the file and then, after all is done, start with a new zip file.

Comment: If you improve the formatting you will have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Remove the return from the else condition. The code stops because of that.

Comment: I am sorry but there are many problems with your code: you don't need that "if filelist:", since you are just iterating a list, which will be fine if the list is empty. You also should use os.path.splitext() to get the filename. You should read your data file out of the file processing loop, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know my code is far from perfect. The problem was with `else`. I moved it to the end of the whole code. It was a novice mistake. I also inserted try-catch so if it fails on one zip file, the next one is still processed. Now, it looks something like this:

```
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip'))
 if filelist:
    for file in filelist:
        try:
            aa = file.split(sl)
            #print "aa ",aa
            bb = aa[len(aa) -1]
            #print "bb ", bb
            cc = bb.split(".")
            #print "cc ", cc
            ime_sole = cc[0]
            #print "imesole ", ime_sole

    fle = codecs.open(rootdir + sl +  'portal_schools.txt','r',encoding="cp1250")
            #line = fle.readline()

            data = []

            for line in iter(fle):
                line = line.replace("\r\n", "")
                x = line.split(";")
                data.append(x)

            result = [element for element in data if element[2] == ime_sole]
            fle.close()
            #print result


            if result:
                database =  result[0][1]

                vnos_data = "Podatki za %s , se vpisujejo v bazo %s " % (ime_sole, database)


                host ="####"
                user="####"
                password = "####"


                iUrnik_tables = iUrnik_tables_fromzip.Tables(defdir,file,sl,host,database,user,password)

                id_skripte =iUrnik_tables[0]
                date_begin = iUrnik_tables[1]
                date_end = iUrnik_tables[2]
                iUrnik_all_fromzip.FileWork(defdir,file,sl,host,database,user,password)


                iUrnik_itt_zip.Proces(defdir,file,sl,host,database,user,password,id_skripte,date_begin,date_end)


                trenutek  = datetime.datetime.now()
                trenutek = trenutek.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")

                newfilename = os.path.splitext(file)[0] 
                newfilename = newfilename +"_" + str(trenutek) + os.path.splitext(file)[1]


                folder = defdir + sl + ime_sole + sl + "archive"

                destination = folder  + sl

                novoimezipa= destination + newfilename.split(sl)[-1]

                if not os.path.exists(folder):
                    os.makedirs(folder)
                    os.chdir(folder)


                shutil.copy(file,destination)

                old = destination + file.split(sl)[-1]
                os.rename(old , novoimezipa )


                os.remove(file)



            else:
                nothing :)

                #return
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()


else:
    vnos_nodata= u"V mapi %s ni podatkov za prenos" % (rootdir)
    Logging(defdir, sl, vnos_nodata)
```

I know it is not perfect but it works :)

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~